# How to evaluate the indefinite the delta function?

Tags: dirac-delta

The integral of delta function on the whole real line is well-defined, but one idea came to mind for indefinite integral. But it seems not straightforward and I cannot proceed the following
\begin{align}
\int e^{-at}\delta \left(t-T\right)dt&=\int e^{-at}dH(t-T)=e^{-at}H(t-T)+a\int H(t-T)e^{-at}dt \\
&=e^{-aT}H(t-T)+\ldots
\end{align}
where $H(t)$ is Heaviside function.

Now let the lower limit to be zero and integrate the above to $\infty$.
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty e^{-at}\delta \left(t-T\right)dt=e^{-at}H(t-T)|_0^\infty+\ldots
\end{align}

Comment: We know the $\ldots$ stands for a constant, but what is the exact expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $e^{-at}\delta(t-T) = e^{-aT}\delta(t-T)$ so the primitive distribution (indefinite integral) of $e^{-at}\delta(t-T)$ is $e^{-aT}H(t-T) + C,$ where $C$ is a constant.